# Div won't float left

Tags: css, html

I have added a picture to my div and with the picture I used `position:absolute` to position the blocks I inputted. But when I `float` it left, it goes on the picture but, it doesn't float left. It just stays behind the other. How can i make it float left without using `position: relative`

Code:

```css
#knowledge-div {
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  width: 0 auto;
}
#knowledge-div img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}
.blocks {
  width: 498px;
  height: 50%;
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
}
#green {
  background-color: green;
}
#orange {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div id="knowledge-div">
  <img src="Pictures/biganswer.jpg">
  <div class="blocks" id="green"></div>
  <div class="blocks" id="orange"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can not float elements which have an absolute position. You can maybe try to position it relative or alternatively use margin

Comment: when i move it to the left, the height of the one i am moving moves back to like 10% instead of the 50%, which basically covers the whole div

Comment: You can better  put the element you want to position in its own `div`. You are also floating two elements at the same time and in the same directions wich will also cause troubles. Your question is also not clear enough and not explaining hat you are really doing

Comment: I am trying to create a game where you answer a question, it will remove the blocks until you answer all and reveal the picture. So i need to have all the blocks position above the picture so when they answer, i can use java script to remove it, if its correct. Do you understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#knowledge-div {
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  width: 0 auto;
}
#knowledge-div img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}
.blocks {
  width: 498px;
  height: 50%;
float:left;
}
#green {
  background-color: green;
}
#orange {
      background-color: orange;
}

<div id="knowledge-div">
  <img src="Pictures/biganswer.jpg">
  <div id="green" class="blocks" >Color green</div>
  <div class="blocks" id="orange">Color orange</div>
</div>

No need to define position property in blocks class. Add some text in div for both colors.
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use position: absolute when you want to float elements.

Try something like this:

```css
#knowledge-div {
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  width: 0 auto;
}
#knowledge-div img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}
.blocks {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  float: left;
  clear: none;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="knowledge-div" style="height:100px; background-image:url('https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/styles/image_card_4x3_ratio/public/thumbnails/image/leisa_christmas_false_color.png'); background-color: #cccccc;">

  <div class="blocks" id="green" >Green</div>
  <div class="blocks" id="orange">Orange</div>
  <div style="float:left; clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh i see, i did that but how do you get the green and orange on the picture? If i use "Position:relative" it will leave empty spaces and when i add new content, the website will think there is something there and push it down.

Comment: I don't think you can achieve that via just by floating. Can't you use it as a background on the parent div? Check the updated code.

Answer (score 0):

The position of an element defined by absolute does not changes, until or unless you make it relative, define padding or margin. When you try to move an element and it does not have enough space to reside then it shifts the neighboring elements.